# Map Bytecode of Function to Function Within Entire Bytecode

Tags: solidity, evm, bytecode

Is it possible to distinguish a functions bytecode out of an entire contracts bytecode? For example, when I pull the bytecode from a contract address, I get something like:

`0x6060604052361561003d576000357c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009004806347966bc21461004e5761003d565b61004c5b61004961005d565b5b565b005b61005b600480505061005d565b005b739e0b9ddba97dd4f7addab0b5f67036...`

Is it a fact that a functions bytecode representation is in this output? For example, would a function be within this bytecode (shown in grey):

0x6060604052361561003d576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900`4806347966bc21461004e5761003d565b6100`4c5b61004961005d565b5b565b005b61005b600480505061005d565b005b739e0b9ddba97dd4f7addab0b5f67036?

Comment: Yes, but you need to know the function's name and the types of its input arguments in order to find it in the bytecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler does not have to put function body into contract bytecode as a consequent range.  Actually, optimizing compiler could decide to inline small functions used only in few places, i.e. copy their bytecode into every place the function is actually used.

However, I believe, current versions of Solidity does not do this.  The body of the unction usually starts with `JUMPDEST` opcode (`0x5b`) and ends with `JUMP` opcode (`0x56`).

You may try to compile your smart contract with `--asm` option and review produced assembly file to find out exactly what bytecode your function was translated into.